Does it always "have to be" a Borg Queen?
In the primary Star trek Canon (And limited to the parts of the franchise that are a canonical continuation of The Original Series and TNG), as opposed to mirror universe, alternative timelines, non canonical video games, etc: Do the Borg always purposefully create a Queen each time their previous Queen needs replacing?
For example, are there instances of them having a King, or member of a race that has additional genders, or no gender at all?

She brings order from chaos, something her species seems uniquely capable of doing.

That's the justification for the species, I was more wondering if it had to be a queen every time, or if they have a queen because this particular individual happened to be female.

A Queen might a given. I'm guessing that the Borg society was modeled by the writers after insect societies built around a reproductive Queen. In this case,  a Queen who directs assimilation of individuals and entire races.

I second @PatWagnerDenver - “Queen” is the term used by analogy with insects. It’s unclear what the natural language of the Borg is, or how they would refer to the Queen, as we only ever hear them speaking English, usually through their version of universal translation.

Personally I thought any Borg 'leader' was a mistake, they were more interesting when it seemed none of them was allowed to be more than a mere drone- the dark side of equality, if you will.

@Nu'Daq - I agree completely but I think they felt they needed to have a "personal" antagonist for the movie.
